# How can I alter this minified if statement?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, minify

I have a minified if statement in a library I'm using that I'm trying to alter here:

```
if (c = a.instances[c["data-cke-widget-id"]])
    d = b.getFirst(g.isParserWidgetElement),
    f.push({
        wrapper: b,
        element: d,
        widget: c,
        editables: {}
    }),
    "1" != d.attributes["data-cke-widget-keep-attr"] && delete d.attributes["data-widget"]
```

The very last line throws the error because `d` can be null at times.  I'm trying to wrap this in a check to see if `d` exists before continuing.  I've been unsuccessful so far because this block of code isn't like normal if statements with it's missing brackets after the `if` and no semi-colons after lines.  Is there a way to encapsulate the final line here in another if statement?

Comment: Generally you don't alter minified code, you alter the original source and minify it again.

Comment: Change that line to: `d && "1" != d.attributes["data-cke-widget-keep-attr"] && delete d.attributes["data-widget"]`

Comment: I realize I shouldn't be touching minified code but for this particular library I don't have access to the source code (it's older) and saw online that this is a popular bug that you have to dig into this ugliness to fix.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The current code, translated a bit more sanely, looks something like this:

```
if (c = a.instances[c["data-cke-widget-id"]]){
  d = b.getFirst(g.isParserWidgetElement);
  f.push({
    wrapper: b,
    element: d,
    widget: c,
    editables: {}
  });
  if ("1" != d.attributes["data-cke-widget-keep-attr"]) {
    delete d.attributes["data-widget"];
  }
}
```

If the last couple lines sometimes throw an error because of `d`, just add a null check before accessing `d.attributes`:

```
if (c = a.instances[c["data-cke-widget-id"]]){
  d = b.getFirst(g.isParserWidgetElement);
  f.push({
    wrapper: b,
    element: d,
    widget: c,
    editables: {}
  });
  if (d !== null && "1" != d.attributes["data-cke-widget-keep-attr"]) {
    delete d.attributes["data-widget"];
  }
}
```

But you really shouldn't be trying to alter minified code - you should alter the *source* code, which then gets pushed through the build process and minified automatically.